# Highlighting tab in p:tabview when I click a corresponding button

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using multiple tabs in `p:tabview`. On top of this I have a series of static image (like progress bar) so that when I click the first image it move on to highlight the first tab and so on.

```
<h:form>
<h:commandLink action="#tab1">
<h:graphicImage src="image1"/>
</h:commandLink>
<p:tabView>
<p:tab title="tab1" id="tab1">
<ui:include src="some.xhtml></ui:include>
</p:tab>
.
.
.
.
</p:tabview>
<h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid ajax requests you should be able to change tabs using jQuery. In order to do that you will need to specify a widgetVar to you tabView.

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" widgetVar="tabViewVar">
....
</p:tabView>
```

With this approach you can use only the image

```
<h:graphicImage value="image1" onclick="jQuery(jQuery(tabViewVar.jqId + " li[role=tab] a").get(0)).trigger("click");" />
<h:graphicImage value="image2" onclick="jQuery(jQuery(tabViewVar.jqId + " li[role=tab] a").get(1)).trigger("click");" />
<h:graphicImage value="image3" onclick="jQuery(jQuery(tabViewVar.jqId + " li[role=tab] a").get(2)).trigger("click");" />
...
```

In case you don't mind extra ajax requests, you can do that as follows:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{tabViewBean.submit}" process="@this" update="tabView">
            <h:graphicImage value="image1" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="0" target="#{tabViewBean.activeIndex}" />
        </p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink action="#{tabViewBean.submit}" process="@this" update="tabView">
            <h:graphicImage value="image2" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="1" target="#{tabViewBean.activeIndex}" />
        </p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink action="#{tabViewBean.submit}" process="@this" update="tabView">
            <h:graphicImage value="image3" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="2" target="#{tabViewBean.activeIndex}" />
        </p:commandLink>
```